# C++11 generator implementation emulating Python's yield keyword

Tags: c++, c++11, thread-safety, iteration, generator

C++11's range-based loops allow convenient and easy iteration over containers, but what about more complicated iterations such as tree traversal? Usually this involves a lot of boilerplate code and potential errors since we need to write complicated iterator classes as well as some wrapper class proving `begin()` and `end()` methods. I simplify process this by implementing a generator class using threads and exceptions that mimics Python's `yield` syntax.

Very simple example:

```
Generator<int> range(int max){
  return Generator<int>([=](Yield<int> &yield){
    for(int i = 0;i<max;++i) yield(i);
  });
}

int main(){
  for(int i:range(10)) std::cout << i << std::endl;
}
```

Is the following implementation correct and safe? Are there better ways to do this (besides switching to more suitable concepts such as visitors)? Any comments are welcome.

```
#include <thread>
#include <future>
#include <memory>
#include <exception>
#include <iterator>

template <class T> class Generator;

template <class T> class Yield{

  enum State{ WAITING,READY,TERMINATED,FINISHED } state = WAITING;

  friend Generator<T>;
  std::promise<T> promise;
  std::mutex mutex;
  std::condition_variable ready_wait;

  struct FinishedException:public std::exception{ };
  struct TerminatedException:public std::exception{ };

  void terminate(){
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(mutex);
    if(state != FINISHED){
      state = TERMINATED;
      ready_wait.notify_one();
    }
  }

  void finish(){
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
    while(state == WAITING) ready_wait.wait(lock);
    if(state == TERMINATED) return;
    state = FINISHED;
    throw FinishedException();
  }

  template <class E> void set_exception(E e){
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
    while(state == WAITING) ready_wait.wait(lock);
    if(state == TERMINATED) return;
    promise.set_exception(e);
  }

  std::future<T> get_future(){
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(mutex);
    promise = std::promise<T>();
    ready_wait.notify_one();
    state = READY;
    return promise.get_future();
  }

  Yield(){ }

  public:
  void operator()(const T &value){
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
    while(state == WAITING) ready_wait.wait(lock);
    if(state == TERMINATED) throw TerminatedException();
    promise.set_value(value);
    state = WAITING;
  }

};

template <class T> class Generator{
  std::function<void(Yield<T> &)> generator_function;

  public:
  Generator(const std::function<void(Yield<T> &)> &gf):generator_function(gf){ }

  class const_iterator:public std::iterator<std::input_iterator_tag,T>{
    friend Generator;

    struct Data{
      Yield<T> yield;
      T current_value;
      std::thread thread;
      ~Data(){ yield.terminate(); thread.join(); }
    };

    std::unique_ptr<Data> data;

    public:
    const T &operator*(){ return data->current_value; }
    const T *operator->(){ return &data->current_value; }

    void operator++(){
      try{
        data->current_value = data->yield.get_future().get();
      }
      catch(typename Yield<T>::FinishedException){
        data.reset();
      }
    }

    bool operator!=(const const_iterator &other){ return data != other.data; }
  };

  const_iterator begin()const{
    const_iterator it;
    it.data.reset(new typename const_iterator::Data);
    auto data = it.data.get();

    data->thread = std::thread([this,data](){
      try{
        generator_function(data->yield);
        data->yield.finish();
      }
      catch(typename Yield<T>::TerminatedException){

      }
      catch(...){
        data->yield.set_exception(std::current_exception());
      }
    });

    ++it;

    return it;
  }

  const_iterator end()const{
    return const_iterator();
  }

};
```

The full source and more examples are located [here](https://github.com/TheLartians/Generator).

*Edit 1: fixed a bug where yield.set_exception() could cause a promise_already_satisfied exception*